# From a Flex application, how to encrypt a string using SHA1 and convert it to base64 string?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I don't know much about actionscript, can anybody throw me an URL on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AS3 Crypto](http://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/) is the best encryption library I have found for actionscript.  I have used it and it works great.

It is also under BSD License.